# Can I say in spite of I calling her,she gave me no answer

Tags: grammar

In spite of I calling her,she gave me no answer

Answer (score 3):

The conflict in your sentence is between the first-person pronoun in the nominative coming right after a preposition, which doesn't really work.

More idiomatic:

> "In spite of **me** calling her ..."

More up-register:

> "In spite of **my** calling her ..."

Comment: I would say "Despite calling, she gave me no answer." This makes "calling" more ambiguous but it is implied that you called since you are the direct object of the sentence

Comment: Your sentence does not make clear whether your call (presumably a phone call) actually got through to her. You might not have reached her, she might have rejected the call or she might have been busy on the line when you called.

Comment: What does that have to do with the issue at hand?